# WordPress IF statement isn't outputting ELSE

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have a straightforward `if` statement to evaluate whether or not an image is set to appear as the logo on a WordPress build. If it returns `empty`/`false`, it displays a default image whose location is set as an absolute value.

The problem is when an image ISN'T set, the else statement is failing. I'm not receiving an error, but the code returned is simply an image tag without any source i.e. "< img src >".

Here is the statement:

```
<?php 
$logo = $wp_options['header_logo'];

if(isset($logo) && ($logo !='')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $logo['url']; ?>">
<?php  } else {  ?>
    <img src="wp-content/themes/wpdev/images/logo.png">
<?php } ;?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *isn't working*? Is there any error or is it just not behaving as you'd expect?

Comment: You should consider using `!empty($logo)` instead of `isset($logo) && ($logo !='')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that if statement is failing, because you are treating `$logo` variable as a string.

It seems you're using `$logo` variable as an array, if you want to check out if it is empty you can use `is_null()` function of PHP.

By the way, we can't understand your problem this way, you should be more specific. Share your error or warning messages, the way it's behaving, etc..

Comment: Yeah, pretty much the solution I found out, I've posted it below. I set the variable a little more specifically within the array and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks st.!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this by specifically referring to the url of the image array when the variable $logo was defined. This way, the IF is evaluating the URL of the image.

The problem seemed to be that the initial IF was being evaluated as TRUE but obviously not returning the URL as this wasn't originally specified in $logo. By looking for the URL in the 'header_logo' array, it corrected the problem.

```
           <?php 
            $logo = $wp_options['header_logo']['url'];

            if(isset($logo) && ($logo !='')) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>">
            <?php  } else {  ?>
                <img src="<!-- Image Location -->">
            <?php } ;?>
```